# Where to put large readonly file that needs random access in android application?

Tags: c#, android, large-files, randomaccessfile

I tried seeking file from both raw and assets folders. No one worked. [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard/25988337#25988337) similar problem is solved by copying file to external storage, but with file as large as 700 MB one would like not to duplicate it on a mobile device. **What is common way working with files this big on android?**

Comment: Depends on what the file contents are? Is it binary? ASCII? Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Download the file. Then work with it using ordinary I/O, as a file.

Comment: File is binary. Tried the Assets.Open( ... Access.Random), but stream is the same as with raw folder, can't be seeked. Didn't try much more.